# Fetch records with double deep associated records

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-activerecord, model-associations

I have a 3 simple models, let's call them Sector, Department, Office.
Sector has many departments and departments has many offices.

Now I want to get all the sectors with at least a department that has at least an office.

I tried a couple of different ways and they "more or less" work. I mean I get what I want if I call Sector.with_offices however If I chain some pretty common methods, such as .size (that adds a count to the original query), I get an unexpected results. Here what I have tried:

```
scope :with_offices, joins(:departments => :offices).group('sectors.id')
scope :with_offices, joins(:departments => :offices).select("DISTINCT sectors.*")
```

I also tried using `uniq`:

```
scope :with_offices, joins(:departments => :offices).uniq
```

But, it has the same issue.

```
Sector.with_offices.size # => 5 (WRONG VALUE)
s = Sector.with_offices # => [#<Sector ... >]
s.size # => 3 (RIGHT VALUE)
```

If I chain size I get the wrong number.

What's a clean way to get sectors with offices and keep size working as expected?

UPDATE 1 - THE SQL QUERIES
Here my queries, I forgot to mention that both associations have a conditions clause that restrict on the state (as shown below).

```
irb(main):010:0> Sector.with_offices.size
   (0.6ms)  SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(*) FROM "sectors" INNER JOIN "departments" ON "departments"."sector_id" = "sectors"."id" AND departments.state IN ('active', 'deactivated') INNER JOIN "offices" ON "offices"."department_id" = "departments"."id" AND offices.state IN ('active', 'deactivated') WHERE "sectors"."state" IN ('active', 'deactivated')
=> 5


irb(main):011:0> s = Sector.with_offices
  Sector Load (0.6ms)  SELECT DISTINCT "sectors".* FROM "sectors" INNER JOIN "departments" ON "departments"."sector_id" = "sectors"."id" AND departments.state IN ('active', 'deactivated') INNER JOIN "offices" ON "offices"."department_id" = "departments"."id" AND offices.state IN ('active', 'deactivated') WHERE "sectors"."state" IN ('active', 'deactivated')
```

UPDATE 2 - THE ASSOCIATIONS

```
Class Sector < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :departments , conditions: ["departments.state IN ('active', 'deactivated')"]
end

Class Department < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :offices , conditions: ["offices.state IN ('active', 'deactivated')"]
end
```

Comment: Hm, that's strange. Could you also add the generated SQL from the log for each of these two situations? Maybe that gives a clue about the problem. I tried it in one of my own projects that has three models with a `has_many` relationship to each other and it returned the correct number whether I saved it in a variable first or not. Also the same SQL is generated in both cases.

Comment: Update1 contains the SQL. Thx

Comment: So what does your scope look like *exactly*? Any conditions are very relavant to your question.

Comment: The scope itself looks like the one above (the one you suggested) [scope :with_offices, joins(:departments => :offices).uniq]

Comment: Where does the condition come from? Also, what Rails version are you using? The first SQL is obviously wrong. It should be `SELECT DISTINCT COUNT("sectors".*)`. When I try this the generated SQL is completely different.

Comment: Rails 3.2.12 with Ruby 1.9.3-p327

Comment: OK, let me try to replicate this... Database is Sqlite, I presume?

Comment: PostgreSQL actually. Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried it and it's a bug in 3.2.12, which has apparently been fixed in 3.2.13. If you upgrade to 3.2.13 the correct SQL will be generated.